# Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()? with jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs

The warning doesn't happen during debug or release mode builds but when testing App.js:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { LocalizationProvider } from 'library/localization';
import NavigationService from 'library/NavigationService';
import AppNavigator from 'library/AppNavigator';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <LocalizationProvider>
        <AppNavigator
          ref={(navigatorRef) => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </>
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));

export default App;
```

the error doesn't appear if I remove the ref from AppNavigator.

AppNavigator.js

```
const guestUserNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen
    },
    Logout: {
      screen: LogoutActivity
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Login'
  }
);

const userNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);





const App = createSwitchNavigator({
  loader: {
    screen: AuthLoadingScreen
  },
  Auth: {
    screen: guestUserNavigation
  },
  App: {
    screen: userNavigation
  }
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(App, {
  initialRouteName: 'loader'
});
export default AppNavigator;
```

App.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-native-testing-library';
import App from './App';

describe('App', () => {
    it('should render the App', () => {
        const result = render(<App />).toJSON();
        expect(result).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

**mocks**/react-navigation.js

```
jest.mock('react-navigation', () => ({
  createAppContainer: jest
    .fn()
    .mockReturnValue(function NavigationContainer(props) {
      return null;
    }),
  createSwitchNavigator: jest.fn(),
  NavigationActions: {
    navigate: jest.fn().mockImplementation((x) => x)
  }
}));
```

now the test passes with the following warning that is bugging me and I cant seem to get it to work:

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
        
Check the render method of `App`.
in NavigationContainer (at App.js:29)
in LocalizationProvider (at App.js:28)
in App (at App.test.js:7)
```

using forwardRef works but then the app doesn't render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppNavigator` shouldn't return `null` because this makes the mock useless to test `App`.

In order to receive a ref, `AppNavigator` should be class or `forwardRef` component. `createAppContainer` arguments can be optionally represented in element hierarchy in order to be testable by a snapshot:

```
...
createAppContainer: jest.fn((Comp, options) => React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <div data-testid="AppContainer" ref={ref}>
    <div data-testid="createAppContainer component">
      {Comp.name}
    </div>
    <div data-testid="createAppContainer options">
      {JSON.stringify(options)}
    </div>
    {children}
  </div>;
})),
...
```